# How to get result URL from QR Code Scanner clickable?

Tags: java, android-studio, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I just follow this tutorial video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe7F4Jx7rwo

And in the end after we scanned the QR Code, it only show a text even if its a link. How can I change it to clickable link from url that I put from my QR Code?

Here's my code that I use in `MainActivity`:

```
private Button scan_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
    final Activity activity = this;
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator Integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            Integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            Integrator.setPrompt("SCAN NOW");
            Integrator.setCameraId(0);
            Integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            Integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            Integrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents()==null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }
    }}}
```

Comment: Clickable in what?  In a document?

Comment: Its a URL link, I want to go to the browser app that smartphone used.

Comment: You didn't answer my actual question.  What android UI element should the URL be clickable in?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0ELtF like this

Comment: Well that looks like pretty straightforward coding to achieve.  What is the problem?

Comment: well if you see the video, the result only show a text

Comment: @StephenC can you help me?

Comment: I still don't see what your problem is.  As I said, making a URL display in a android browser is simple, and solutions are easy to find: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133628/display-url-in-webview, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application

Comment: @StephenC where should I put the webview code in my code? Sorry i'm new to this.

Comment: @StephenC can you help me?

Comment: I have already helped you.  But I am not going to write your code for you.  Read the links I provided.

Comment: @StephenC Should I change the code from activityresult and replace it with webview?

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying.  Also, please reread my last comment, and stop bugging me.

Comment: @StephenC I'm sorry. Thank you for helping me.